# Is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$ always even?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, summation

Is
$$ f(n,x,y)=\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}{n\choose k}x^{n-k}y^k,\qquad\qquad\forall~n>0~\text{and}~x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$$
always divisible by $2$?

Comment: Having $100$% $\LaTeX$ on the title isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

(Hint)
An odd number raised to any power is odd, and an even number raised to any power is even.
In particular,
$$
(x + y)^n \equiv (x + y) \pmod 2
$$
Using this along with the binomial formula, you should be able to prove the result.

Comment: Yes, but your congruence is weak. It should be $(x+y)^n\equiv (x^n+y^n)\pmod{2}$, correct?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh that is true as well (in fact that is true for any prime).  However, in the particular case of mod 2, I usually just replace all $n$th powers with the number itself, because it makes things simpler.

Comment: But you are correct that using $(x + y)^n \equiv x^n + y^n$ makes the proof more direct.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, Goos and Norbert have given the answer. (And you should also assume $n\in \mathbb{N}$)

$$
f(n,x,y) = (x+y)^n - x^n -y^n
$$

If

- both $x$ and $y$ are even: even - even - even = even;
- both $x$ and $y$ are odd: even - odd - odd = even;
- $x$ is even and $y$ is odd: odd - even - odd = even;
- $y$ is odd and $x$ is even: just like the case above.

So, $f(n,x,y)$ is always even.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Recall binomial formula
$$
(x+y)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} x^{n-k} y^k
$$

Comment: Yes, I know that. This is how I came to the above result.

Comment: Ok do you know anything about Frobenius automorphism?

Comment: I've used Frobenius in an elementary differential equations course.

Comment: I might be able to manage if you can explain it clearly.

Comment: bin-o-mail? That sounds like an automatic mail deleter! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you, I'm downloading it now.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting $y=-x+a$ and expand the powers.